# Recommended Methods to save Actual Location Addresses to Database and Query

Tags: database, google-maps-api-3, database-design, street-address

I have a real estate management application that I need to save the Property Address for.

I was originally going to save it as raw data (address, city, state), but I want the user to be able to query the other user's properties based on address (let's assume I have 10,000 properties, I want them to query it, raw addresses I think may be difficult to use).

**Question 1:**
What is the recommended method to save location addresses to the database?

**Potential Solutions:**

Solution 1: save it as raw address, city state.

Solution 2: Save raw address but use database for city and state information.

Solution 3: Use geo location lat/long. I think i don't want to do this because the address can get misinterpretted.

**Question 2**: I would like to integrate a google autocomplete for finding an address. I don't know if this is feasible for what i'm trying to do. Any recommendations?

Any advice is greatly appreciated! Looking this up is difficult since "address" and "location" can mean a lot of things in the coding world.

Comment: I'm pretty desperate, any one have any insights?

Comment: There are more insights in the related questions that might help you. I found this answer to be particularly insightful https://stackoverflow.com/q/54253971/4462191

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here are the relevant sources I found to come to a conclusion of my search.

1. [Best practices for storing postal addresses in a database (RDBMS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310540/best-practices-for-storing-postal-addresses-in-a-database-rdbms) is roughly a duplicate of this
2. [Is this a good way to model address information in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307027/is-this-a-good-way-to-model-address-information-in-a-relational-database) is insightful
3. https://smartystreets.com/articles/address-apis is an api which can do what I'm discussion, and i'm sure there are alternatives to this if you look that up.